# How to filter and smooth the curve into straight line

Tags: time-series, smoothing, simplification

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcEDR.png)
In this first picture, the line represents the velocity change during the taking off period of the plane. I want to smooth this curve and replace it with straight lines and then to identify the trend of every section.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejwXU.jpg)

In this second picture, I draw what I want to get and replace all this signal into several straight lines.

What I have tried:
1 Smoothing technique :
Savgol_filter; Gaussian filter
Python model tsmoothie
2 Line simplification algos
Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm

However, it is hard to find a appropriate parameter to identify all the time series. (This means to define the rise,flat and fall period) However this change of velocity has a pattern to follow: normally it gets two or three platforms.

I don't know if there exists some paper or algorithm to handle this kind of problem

Here are other examples of time series to model
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qdJF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nA1sr.jpg)

Comment: There is only 1 picture.

Comment: there are actually 4 pictures but they show as links described as (enter image description here) You couldn't open them?